# Why are singleton Puppet Arrays Strings in my ruby code?

Tags: ruby, puppet

I've create a custom type in Puppet (simplified for this example). If I use it like this (two items in `collections`)...

```
 my_type { "example1":
    ensure => present,
    collections => ["abc", "def"]
  }
```

...in my provider, `resource[:collections]` is of type `Array`. That is good, and right.

But if `collections` contains only 1 item...

```
 my_type { "example2":
    ensure => present,
    collections => ["abc"],
  }
```

...`resource[:collections]` is a `String`, which is most disconcerting, and a pain in the ass to deal with.

Is this a Ruby thing, a Puppet thing (I'm new to both) or just some cosmic wrinkle in the coding universe I've stumbled upon? And more importantly, is there a workaround? Or am I just plain doing it wrong? I've been told that before. Don't hold back.

Comment: Does this actually run? For me, it's a syntax error.

Comment: Also, `ensure` is a reserved word

Comment: It will run if I've extended Puppet with a custom type called 'my_type', and implemented the methods necessary to support the `ensure` contract, which is what I'm trying to do. And it works, just not as cleanly as I'd hoped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I can't tell you why this happens, the standard workaround for dealing with things that can be either arrays or single objects is using the splat operator like this:`[*foo]`. In case `foo` was an array its elements will be "exploded" into a new one, so you still have an array. If `foo` was just a plain object, you now have a one element array.

Comment: that just shifts the problem. Puppet DSL `["abc"]` now "correctly" gives me an Array with one entry in the Ruby code, but `["abc","def"]` gives me an Array within an Array (i.e. `[["abc","def"]]` in the Ruby code).

Comment: That's interesting, the second case should get flattened if you use splat. Puppet indeed must be doing something strange here.

Comment: You are correct. My mistake. I was not printing it out correctly. Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a Ruby thing.

```
resource = { :collection => ["abc"] }
resource[:collection].class
=> Array
```

It seems a bit odd if the Puppet DSL would change that behavior since it's Ruby based after all. But if it really does you can take Michaels' advice. Example:

```
[*resource[:collection]]
=> ["abc"]
resource[:str]="abc"
resource[:str]
=> "abc"
[*resource[:str]]
=> ["abc"]
```

Comment: Thanks, good to know that it must be the way Puppet passes the data to Ruby.